# Resistor like symbol android

Tags: android-10, android-one

[image]

For a couple of days, this weird symbol that looks like a variable resistor has been showing on my android one (Moto one power) device.
What is that supposed to be? How do I get rid of it

I've played around with the volume/vibrate, every developer options, along with disabling the developer options altogether.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the issue was. Leaving it out here if someone else encounters this as well. This icon essentially means 'Sensors off'. The symbol was the reason my camera was not working as well.
Inside the developer options, under quick developer tiles, there is a 'Sensors off' option.

Not sure why disabling the developer options did not revert back the change though.

Comment: Disabling the developer menu does not affect the settings you have made, it just hides the menu. The only thing that might get deactivated by hiding the menu is the Android Debug Bridge (adb) connection.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I thought that all the developer changes get undone, because the accent color that I sent in the developer settings reverted back to default on disabling the developer option.